# How to Solve This Integral With Multiple Variables? I think I should use partial fraction decomposition.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-fractions

The problem is the integral of $$\int {\frac{-8 x}{x^4-a^4}}\, dx$$

I factored out the -8 and divided the x.

I tried to use partial fraction decomposition but it wasn't forming into something I could work with. When I tried to group them I had way too many to match the form of the denominator. I feel like I might be using the wrong integration method but I don't know what else I could use.

[Work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laTzZ.png)

[image]

(Sorry I redrew my work on my computer so I wouldn't have a crappy picture of my notebook)

> My Attempt:
> [Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHAgI.png)
> [Part2/Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsFSX.png)
> Which gave me the answer:
> $$4\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\ln |x^2-a^2|-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln |x^2-a^2|\right)+C$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider a $u$-substitution (choose $u$ based off the variable in the numerator).

Comment: $xdx=1/2 d(x^2)$. Substitute $y=x^2$. Get $\int \frac {4dy}{y^2-a^4}=4\int \frac{dy}{(y-a^2)(y+a^2)}$. Then use partial fractions.

Comment: Or possibly plus in the inverse hyperbolic tangent form.

Comment: Hyperbolic tangent form is not needed. This is a difference of two logarithms.

Comment: That too. I use either depending on the phase of the Moon or whatever.

Comment: @markvs Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that

$$
I=\int \frac{-8 x}{x^{4}-a^{4}} d x=-4 \int \frac{d\left(x^{2}\right)}{\left(x^{2}\right)^{2}-\left(a^{2}\right)^{2}}
$$

Let $y=x^{2}$ and $b=a^{2}$, then

$$\begin{aligned} I &=-4 \int \frac{d y}{y^{2}-b^{2}}\\&=-4 \int \frac{1}{2 b}\left(\frac{1}{y-b} -\frac{1}{y+b}\right) d y \\ &=-\frac{2}{b}(\ln |y-b|-\ln |y+b|)+C \\ &=-\frac{2}{a^{2}} \ln \left|\frac{x^{2}-a^{2}}{x^{2}+a^{2}}\right|+C \\ &=\frac{2}{a^{2}} \ln \left|\frac{x^{2}+a^{2}}{x^{2}-a^{2}}\right|+C \end{aligned}$$